# selenium .getElementsBy() index 0 vs single .getElementBy()

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, filtering

I'm learning Selenium and have a question that I cant find the answer to.

Apart from the "By" locator, is there any real difference in specification between
`WebDriver.getElementsBy().get(0)` 
vs single
`WebDriver.getElementBy()`

are they coming from the same source? do they have the same approach internally? will it affect my test cases if I start using `getElementsBy().get(0)` always instead of the single one?'

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `getElementBy()` internally uses `getElementsBy().get(0)` so they are functionally ALMOST the same.

See the [source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/By.java):

```java
  /**
   * Find a single element. Override this method if necessary.
   *
   * @param context A context to use to find the element.
   * @return The WebElement that matches the selector.
   */
  public WebElement findElement(SearchContext context) {
    List<WebElement> allElements = findElements(context);
    if (allElements == null || allElements.isEmpty()) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException("Cannot locate an element using " + toString());
    }
    return allElements.get(0);
  }
```

**The difference** is that you will get Exception if the lookup of `getElementBy()` will fail, unlike the latter case when you will not.

Comment: Strange... W3C standard mentions 2 separate methods: find element and find elementS  -> the second one returns json array;
in .net implementation
`public virtual IWebElement FindElement(string mechanism, string value)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            parameters.Add("using", mechanism);
            parameters.Add("value", value);
            Response commandResponse = this.Execute(DriverCommand.FindElement, parameters);
            return this.GetElementFromResponse(commandResponse);
        }
`

Comment: Yes, but Java bindings use elements lookup. I think this is because W3C standard is young enough so that not all the clients support it completely.

Answer (score 1):

1. findElement() is used to find first web element on current page by provided locator mechanism such as id, xpath, css etc whereas findElements() is used to find all web elements on current page by provided locator mechanism such as id, xpath, css etc.
2. findElement() will return only first web element even provided locator locates more than one web element. findElements() returns all matching web elements. findElement() method internally calls findElements() method itself and return first indexed web element.
3. Return type of findElement() method is a WebElement whereas return type of findElements() method is a List.
4. findElement() will throw NoSuchElementException if no matching element is found. findElements() will return an empty list if no matching element is found. This is the reason findElements() is a better way for checking non-presence of web element. Kindly concentrate on this point more. NoSuchElementException is thrown by findElement() not findElements().

**Conclusion:** Use findelements where possible because you will avoid NoSuchElementException , also it should be faster because findelement is calling findelements and returns only firt element if found.